# Google App Script to reply to Slack with 200 and run the actual code

Tags: google-apps-script, slack, slack-api

I have used google app script to make an interactive app in Slack. Most of the time it works as I want it to, but in one of the steps the app has to retrieve all the issues from Jira and attach it in the payload, also contact an external API to create a progress chart etc. In short it is a time intensive process and sometimes it fails because Slack does not get a reply within 3 seconds.

I tried using the trigger builder but unfortunately it has a +-15m accuracy in a millisecond input... I need the interactions to be fairly instant.

If anyone knows and could share another way to make this happen, it would really help.

Thank you

Comment: Hi ! Could you please share a minimal reproducible code sample? Could you reference what you mean by trigger builder? Are you using [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) and if so which type of [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) are you using?

Comment: Hi @MateoRandwolf, I am using Apps Script. For a case I first send a simple interactable object on my payload. Then I have a script to interact with slack:
doPost(e){
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunctionToSendAnotherPayloadOrDoOtherStuff")
  .timeBased()
  .after(100)
  .create();

}

Comment: So, your issue is that you want your function which is run with a time based trigger to wait for the requests to be completed (as Slack might return an error at first) right? So your main problem is that slack might return an error but you want to wait for Slack to not return an error right?

Comment: My issue is that, Slack expects first a 200 OK reply in 3 seconds, then I have 30min to process my data, run functions etc. and send my actual payload. Currently I don't reply with 200OK the first time, which makes it difficult to complete my process and reply in 3 seconds. To fix this I tried to use the time trigger above, so that I first reply to Slack with 200OK when user interacts with my object in slack, then after 100ms I tried to run my actual function to send my actual payload. However this is not very accurate, at minimum the actual function runs after 20-30s.

Comment: I don't really focus on getting an error from Slack, just mainly looking for a way such that after someone interacts with my slack app I get a payload from Slack, reply to slack that I got the payload, and then send my next payload. However these should be done as back to back as possible, as to not make the user wait until time trigger runs.

Comment: So basically your main problem is that the time trigger has a too large time scale for your purpose right? Your problem is that you cannot run a function 100ms after you send the first reply to Slack right? Are you sending this first reply to slack from Apps Script too?

Comment: Yes, everything is from the same script. The function doesn't run 100ms after first reply to slack with 200. It takes around 20s or so to start running but it is generally varying in time. 
If I could just do:
doPost(e){

ScriptApp.newTrigger("actualFunction") .timeBased() .after(100) .create()

return ContentService.createTextOutput('200 OK')}

and it would run after 100ms I would be alright. So I am looking for a way to return Slack OK, and then continue running my other function.

Comment: Hi ! Could you provide a sample script *with no sensitive data* with the basic structure of your code and how you are trying to implement these two functions? Have you take a look at maybe using [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) or [Utils.sleep()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds) from Apps Script to wait just 100ms between functions?